# How to scope a Laravel model with a calculated criteria of available vs booked capacity?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a simple booking feature, implemented by a `Shifts` model (for availability) and `Bookings` (for reserved shifts).

A `Shift` has a certain level of capacity, so that I consider it *Open* when it's capacity hasn't yet been all booked, and *Closed* if it's capacity was fully booked.

Regarding relationships, a Shift has many Bookings, being each booking a count for 1 resource of capacity being occupied.

My need is to grab all of the *Open Shifts* by using an Eloquent `scope` method, which I consider would be the most natural (Laravelish) way to go about it.

In other words, I want to list shifts with open positions. i.e, shifts with confirmed bookings < shift.people_needed, preferably using scopeOpen.

## Test Scenario

In order to show an example of how my actual DB looks like, I've created [this DB SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cd87/3) which runs the following RAW query that I'd like to translate into the form of a scope method.

```
SELECT shifts.*, COUNT(bookings.id) as num_of_bookings
FROM shifts
    LEFT JOIN bookings on bookings.shift_id = shifts.id
GROUP BY shifts.id
    HAVING shifts.quantity > num_of_bookings
```

My understanding is that I'd have to get something of the form:

```
public function scopeOpen ($query) {
  return $query->whereDoesntHave('bookings', function ($q) {
       // $q->.....
  })
}
```

But I'm honestly struggling to build the correct statement.

---

Any ideas on this are welcome.

### Database Migrations Schema

```
    Schema::create('shifts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id');
        $table->primary('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('client_id')->index();
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');
        $table->unsignedInteger('facility_id')->index();
        $table->foreign('facility_id')->references('id')->on('facilities');
        $table->string('qualification');
        $table->tinyInteger('quantity')->unsigned()->default(1);
        $table->unsignedInteger('rate');
        $table->dateTime('start');
        $table->dateTime('end');
        $table->smallInteger('break')->unsigned()->nullable()->comment('in minutes');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });


    Schema::create('bookings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->unsignedInteger('nurse_id')->index();
        $table->foreign('nurse_id')->references('id')->on('nurses');

        $table->string('shift_id')->index();
        $table->foreign('shift_id')->references('id')->on('shifts');

        $table->string('creator_type')->nullable();
        $table->integer('creator_id')->nullable();
                    
        $table->dateTime('confirmed_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('confirmer_type')->nullable();
        $table->integer('confirmer_id')->nullable();
        
        $table->dateTime('canceled_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('canceler_type')->nullable();
        $table->integer('canceler_id')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

What I want is to list available shifts. i.e shifts with fewer bookings that shift->quantity. (other constrains are not important now).

## Edit

Right now I am using the following local scope. but If you can make it cleaner i.e fewer raw queries, I will be glad.

```
    public function scopeOpen($query)
    {
        return $query->whereRaw("
            quantity > ( select count(*) 
                        from bookings 
                        where shifts.id = bookings.shift_id 
                        and confirmed_at is not null 
                        and canceled_at is null
                     )
            ");
    }
```

Comment: Hi @barghouthi, if you already have a model/db structure it'd be useful if you share some of it. In that case I think I may be able to hint something. I've faced a similar problem some time ago while developing [a package](https://github.com/timegridio/concierge/tree/master/src) from where you might get some ideas.

Comment: @alariva Thank you for stopping by, I updated the question.

Comment: I think your case is similar to the one I faced with Vacancy (shift) and Appointment (Booking). Please [have a look at](https://github.com/timegridio/concierge/blob/master/src/Models/Vacancy.php#L266) the implementation to get some ideas. Basically the scope will return true for the test of availability/capacity (open positions for your case) being greater than the count of the child relationships (bookings) for which you may also filter with certain criteria.

Comment: Alright, I believe we are kinda in the same place. Once I have one shift ( vacancy) it is easy to do all sort if checks on it, But in your application, how do you list all vacancies? I see you have hasRoom(), which is what i want in form of scope, scopeHasRoom(). I suspect i need to do some raw querying.

Comment: Please jump into [this editor](http://collabedit.com/kxka6), maybe we can draft something together.

Comment: Managed to write the sql.

Comment: Good job! I'll edit the post so the intention is clearer and may help fellow devs to understand the need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where other constrained are not important and **"open shifts**" described according to this following rules:

```
shifts where number of bookings < shift quantity.
```

An Eloquent Model local scope that implements this is written as follow

```
function scopeOpen($query)
{
        return $query->withCount('bookings')
                ->whereRaw("quantity > bookings_count");
}
```

> php artisan tinker

```
>>> App\Shift::open()->toSql();
=> "select "shifts".*, (
        select count(*) 
        from "bookings" 
        where "shifts"."id" = "bookings"."shift_id"
    ) as "bookings_count" 
    from "shifts"
    where quantity > bookings_count"
```

Say you that we rule becomes the following:

```
shifts where number of confirmed bookings < shift quantity
```

The local scope can be modified in the following manner.

```
function scopeOpen($query)
{
        return $query->withCount([
                    'bookings' => function ($q) {
                        $q->whereNotNull('bookings.confirmed_at')
                }])
                ->whereRaw("quantity > bookings_count");
}
```

> php artisan tinker

```
>>> App\Shift::open()->toSql();
=> "select "shifts".*, (
        select count(*) 
        from "bookings" 
        where "shifts"."id" = "bookings"."shift_id" 
          and "bookings"."confirmed_at" is not null
    ) as "bookings_count" 
    from "shifts"
    where quantity > bookings_count"
```

**Edit**: AFAIK, the local scope implementation above only works against SQLite database. This below one works against MySQLdb

```
function scopeOpen($query)
{
     return $query->withCount([
        'bookings' => function($q) {
              $q->whereNotNull('bookings.confirmed_at')
        }])
        ->groupBy("shifts.id")
        ->havingRaw("quantity > bookings_count");
}
```

> php artisan tinker

```
>>> App\Shift::open()->toSql();
=> "select "shifts".*, (
      select count(*)
      from "bookings"
      where "shifts"."id" = "bookings"."shift_id" 
          and "bookings"."deleted_at" is null) as "bookings_count" 
    from "shifts" 
    group by "shifts"."id" 
    having quantity = bookings_count"
```

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bookings_count' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `shifts`.*, (select count(*) from `bookings` where `shifts`.`id` = `bookings`.`shift_id` and `bookings`.`confirmed_at` is not null and `bookings`.`canceled_at` is null) as `bookings_count` from `shifts` where quantity > bookings_count)

Comment: this is the result from tinker toSql(): "select `shifts`.*, (
 select count(*) from `bookings` 
 where `shifts`.`id` = `bookings`.`shift_id` 
  and `bookings`.`confirmed_at` is not null 
  and `bookings`.`canceled_at` is null and 
   `bookings`.`deleted_at` is null
 ) as `bookings_count` from `shifts` 
 where quantity > bookings_count and `shifts`.`deleted_at` is null"

Comment: Its not a problem in the scope method. I am running the query directly and getting unknown column 'bookings_count'.

Comment: That's weird. It's not clear to me what you may be missing since `bookings_count` is an alias of the counted bookings. Tinkering with the query doesn't yield an error for me _e.g._ `DB::getPdo()->query(App\Shift::open()->toSql())`

Comment: it doesn't yield an error for me either in tinker. but when i run it i get this error. see here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cd87/25    change bookings_count to a number and it works fine.

Comment: I actually figured out the situation. The query works in SQLite which was what I was testing against and not MySQL. I'll update the scope query for MySQL

Comment: Thank you sir, I will test it tomorrow ;)

Comment: Awesome. Final question if you know, why doesn't this work with paginate. is it a bug? I have it working fine except when I want to paginate the results!

Comment: No, it isn't a bug. `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::paginate` returns a `LengthAwarePaginator`. What it really does is modifies the existing replacing the select clause to `"select count(*) as aggregate"` and using that. This affects the existing scope query. If you wanted to paginate an existing scope query, `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::simplePaginate` is what you want to use.